# jsSHA and Python hashlib give different results for same input

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, hash, hashlib

The following snippets use Nodejs and Python to calculate a hash from the same input content, but they give different results. It's weird.

```
// npm install jssha
const jssha = require("jssha");
var s = new jssha("SHA-1", "TEXT");
s.setHMACKey("abc", "TEXT")
s.update("123")
console.log(s.getHMAC("B64"))
```

The result is `vpEGplDt4B9KMf3iOB0G9ftz5hI=`

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

hashed = hmac.new(b"abc", b"TEXT", hashlib.sha1)
hashed.update("123".encode('utf-8'))
print(base64.b64encode(hashed.digest()).decode())
```

The result is `f1/O4xLhhZgwtm6IMAwLDmjzQgg=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will get the same hmac as javascript:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

hashed = hmac.new(key=b"abc", msg=b"", digestmod=hashlib.sha1)
hashed.update("123".encode('utf-8'))
print(base64.b64encode(hashed.digest()).decode())
# vpEGplDt4B9KMf3iOB0G9ftz5hI=
```

i do not know anything about this javascript api, but i guess `"TEXT"` tells javascript how the data/key is encoded.